# How to change the state of a variable from another child Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `Align` Widget where I show a list item.

```
class _BackgroundState extends State<Background> {
  final List<Widget> list = [
    Text("1"),
    Text("2"),
    Text("3"),
  ];

  int i = 0;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Stack(
       children:[
          Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: list[i],
          BottomMenu()
     ]);
  }

}
```

BottomMenu is **StatelessWidget**

contains multiple `CustomBottomIcon` Widgets that return a `GestureDetector`.

```
class _CustomBottomIconState extends State<CustomBottomIcon> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        //
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        child: Icon(
          widget.icon,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that the index `i` is not visible in the child widget. How can I change the state of `i` ?

> Is it enough to rebuild the list item?

Comment: Declare the function with setState in the parent (in your case `Background` Widget), then pass that function to `BottomMenu` Widget.

Comment: The whole tree has to become stateful though right?

Comment: The highest Widget who needs access to the data is the only one that has to be the StatefulWidget. Your CustomButtonIcon doesn't have to be Stateful, it just needs the setState function argument passed by the parent.

Comment: yeap right! amazing seems to work, although if you would like to follow up with my latest question feel free to do so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611649/how-to-return-a-widget-to-a-previous-state