# How to return a Widget to a previous state

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm changing the color of a custom menu icon, by using the `setState` in my Custom Icon Widget
Although I'd like to change the previous pressed Icon to the previous state (before the color was `Indigo`)

---

### Edit 2:

Live demo: https://alexakis97.github.io/webappjs/

---

By changing the `_color` variable in onTap method I manage to change the color.

To get a better understanding this an Custom Icon Widget:

```
class _CustomBottomIconState extends State<CustomBottomIcon> {
  final Function changeMenu;
  final int index;

  _CustomBottomIconState({this.changeMenu, this.index});

  Color _color = Colors.indigo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        //
        changeMenu(index);
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.green;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        child: Icon(
          widget.icon,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(Middle Icon pressed)

[image]

How can I change the first one back to `Indigo` ?

### Edit 1:

Sharing bottom menu widget

```
class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function changeMenu;
  final Key key;
  BottomMenu({this.changeMenu, this.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 15,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              )),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomBottomIcon(
                    icon: Icons.wallet_travel,
                    index: 0,
                    changeMenu: changeMenu),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                CustomBottomIcon(
                    icon: Icons.person, index: 1, changeMenu: changeMenu),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                CustomBottomIcon(
                    icon: Icons.email, index: 2, changeMenu: changeMenu),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is what the `ChangeMenu` function does:

```
 final List<Widget> list = [
    Text("Work 1"),
    Text("Work 2"),
    Text("Work 3"),
  ];

  int i = 0;

  void changeMenu(index) {
    setState(() {
      i = index;
    });
  }
```

It's placed on another parent widget

Comment: You can either maintain a history of the states directly on your Widget like an Array that you push and pop values when you change and go back respectively. Or you can go with a more robust state solution like BLoC which has a BloC observer that keep this history of state transitions for you

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling CustomButtonIcon ?

Comment: `setState(() {_color = _color == Colors.indigo ? Colors.green : Colors.indigo;});` Can this provide quick fix? For better answer I think you need to share more code as @Shubhamhackz mentioed

Comment: I updated the question guys with more code!

Comment: a quick update for your comment guys, the good part is when you click a `green` icon it returns to it's previous state, although I'm trying to return every other Icon to it's previous state, imagine a simple menu, when you select the middle icon it turns `green` and the other two become `indigo`. I don't know if that makes better sense

Comment: check out a demo here: https://alexakis97.github.io/webappjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like yours it is best to use a state management library such as [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [BloC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). But if you want to stick to your approach, then you will have to modify your code to be the following:

**Custom Icon Widget**

```
class _CustomBottomIconState extends State<CustomBottomIcon> {
  final Function changeMenu;
  final int index;
  final int selectedIndex;

  _CustomBottomIconState({this.changeMenu, this.index, this.selectedIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => changeMenu(index),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.green : Colors.indigo,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        child: Icon(
          widget.icon,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Bottom Menu**

```
class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function changeMenu;
  final Key key;
  final int selectedIndex;
  BottomMenu({this.changeMenu, this.key, this.selectedIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 15,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CustomBottomIcon(
                index: 0,
                icon: Icons.wallet_travel,
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                changeMenu: changeMenu,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              CustomBottomIcon(
                index: 1,
                icon: Icons.person,
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                changeMenu: changeMenu,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              CustomBottomIcon(
                index: 2,
                icon: Icons.email,
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                changeMenu: changeMenu,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Change Menu Function**

```
void changeMenu(int _index) {
  setState(() {
    selectedIndex = _index;
  });
}
```

---

### Explanation

Now for the explanation, what I am doing is that I am doing a technique called state lifting, this technique is highly discouraged since it can get very messy very fast and hard to properly maintain. But for a small portion of the app it is possible to get away with it.

Now what is happening is that we have a main or any class as the parent and is the one managing the state.

Below is the tree representation of your widget structure.

[image: Example]

Now when the icon is clicked, the method in the main (`changeMenu`) is called which takes the index of the icon in the `BottomBar` and set the `selectedIndex` to be it. This will cause a rebuild in Flutter since a state was changed. Therefore the `BottomBar` will be rebuilt, and it will pass the `selectedIndex` to the icons. Inside the icons, there exist a check which checks if the `selectedIndex` is equal to the icon `index`, depending on this check, the color is set.

Note: The initial value of `selectedIndex`, will determine which icon is selected, set it to -1 to make no icon selected.

Comment: Yeap worked ! although I had to do some adjustments!

Comment: Great, I am glad I was able to help you 

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
class _CustomBottomIconState extends State<CustomBottomIcon> {
  final Function changeMenu;
  final int index;

  int _selectedIndex = -1; // by default all button color will be green, if _selectedIndex = 0 the first index color will be indigo

  _CustomBottomIconState({this.changeMenu, this.index});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        //
        changeMenu(index);
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: getColor(index),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
        child: Icon(
          widget.icon,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 Color getColor(int index) {
    if (index == _selectedIndex) {
      return Colors.indigo;
    } else {
      return  Colors.green;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, it doesn't change anything , it's the same, although the colors starting from green. I have to return the color to it's previous state

Comment: instead changeMenu(index), you can return changeMenu(getColor(index)).

Comment: no, changeMenu paremeter is  an `integer`

Comment: So in that case can use this getColor(int index) method in the previous state screen

Comment: yes how am I gonna do that that's the question, visit: https://alexakis97.github.io/webappjs/ and you will understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar idea to a [radio button](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html), which includes two parameters, `value` and `groupValue`. You can implement yours in a similar way: change your `BottomMenu` to a `StatefulWidget`, add a `int groupValue = -1` in your state, and pass this to your `CustomIconButton`, as well as `index`.

You can the choose the colour of your button based on whether `index == groupIndex` inside your `CustomIconButton` and update `groupIndex` in your `BottomMenu` class every time a button is pressed. You can do this by wrapping your `changeMenu` parameter with something like

```
changeMenu: (index) {
    setState(() {
        groupIndex = index;
    });
    changeMenu(index);
},
```

or move this to a separate function.

If you want to turn all of them off when you press one of them a second time, just add this a check to the wrapper function and set `groupIndex` to -1 if it's the same as `index`.

Comment: I'm a little lost, can you provide an example of `CustomBottomIcon` ?